# Change completed to true on button click in Vuejs 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to do a task app in vuejs. I cannot get the button to change from incomplete to complete when clicked. I cannot target the specific button I clicked on to change the completed state to true.

See the example here, https://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/b5wxure9/

**JS**

```
new Vue({

    el: '#tasks',

    data: {
        message: 'Tasks',
        completed: null,
        tasklist: [
            { description: 'Read', completed: true },
            { description: 'Write', completed: true },
            { description: 'Edit', completed: false },
            { description: 'Publish', completed: false }
        ]
    },

    methods: {
        completeTask: function(){
            // console.log(this.tasks.description);
            return this.task.completed = true;
        }
    }

})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="tasks">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            {{ message }}
        </h3>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix" v-for="task in tasklist" >
            {{ task.description }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" v-if="!task.completed" @click="completeTask">Complete</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm completed text-muted pull-right disabled" v-else>Completed</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several you could do this.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" v-if="!task.completed" @click="task.completed = true">Complete</button>
```

If you still want to use the method, pass it the task.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" v-if="!task.completed" @click="completeTask(task)">Complete</button>

methods: {
    completeTask: function(task){
        // console.log(this.tasks.description);
        task.completed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I amazed that you can do it straight on the button. Goodbye methods

Comment: @ClintonGreen it's useful *sometimes*, like in this case where all you want to do is toggle a boolean. You should avoid putting large blocks of logic in the template though.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the index of the task, like:

```
<li class="list-group-item clearfix" v-for="(task, taskIndex) in tasklist" >
  {{ task.description }}
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" v-if="!task.completed" @click="completeTask(taskIndex)">Complete</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm completed text-muted pull-right disabled" v-else>Completed</button>
</li>
```

Then your method can look like:

```
completeTask: function(index){
    return this.tasklist[index].completed = true;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/L5kjvmc6/

Comment: Thanks, great example